# Snowflake & Sqlalchemy connection closed but thread still hangs

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sqlalchemy, database-connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wrote a snowflake & sqlalchemy wrapper to setup a one-time connection to snowflake data warehouse, and one can use this connection to execute multiple queries later. The code is as follows:

```
class SnowFlakeConnection:

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(URL("XXXXX"))
        self.connection = self.engine.connect()               

    def get_df_from_query (self, query):
        '''
        Params: Runs the supplied query
        Return: DataFrame that contains the query Results
        '''
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df = pd.read_sql(query, self.connection)
        df.columns = [x.upper() for x in (df.columns)]

        return df

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        self.connection.close()
        self.engine.dispose()

    def __del__(self):
        self.connection.close()
        self.engine.dispose()
```

Then, I wrote a simple program calling this SnowFlakeConnection module.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    with SnowFlakeConnection() as snowflake_connection:
        snowflake_connection = SnowFlakeConnection()

        ## Making a sample connection
        query = 'SELECT * FROM DB'
        df_res = snowflake_connection.get_df_from_query(query)
        print (df_res)
```

However, while I am able to have `df_res` initiated properly at the end, my main function never terminates. It just hangs in there and not exit. After some investigation, I found out that I created a new thread by calling `self.engine.connect()`  during initialization. However, in the `__exit___` function, I've clearly closed the connection and dispose the engine. In addition, the destructor I wrote does the same job to close the connection and dispose the engine. Why is the thread still there? Why is the program not terminating as I've correctly dispose the engine I created?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you have a second construction within the resource block duplicating the object? That's bound to create a second thread: `snowflake_connection = SnowFlakeConnection()`, just use the `snowflake_connection` created in the `with` block to avoid the double construction?